# Null reference exception getting value from base class

Tags: c#, .net, exception, xna

I have a little engine (defined as `public class ScreenManager : DrawableGameComponent`) to manage input and screens (with transitions etc.), who works with a `public abstract class GameScreen`. For menu screens I have an `abstract class MenuScreen : GameScreen`.
I'm trying to get from `class OptionsMenuScreen : MenuScreen` a value stored in the main class of the game (the one called by Program.cs), but I always get NullReferenceException. I need that value because while starting application I need to get some option and these options can be changed from OptionsMenuScreen, but I want that changes from that screen automatically reflects on the rest of application, so a screen can base it's computation on that value, without force the user to reload entire application to get values in main class updated.
I do this with

```
public ScreenManager ScreenManager
{
    get { return screenManager; }
    internal set { screenManager = value; }
}

ScreenManager screenManager;
```

in GameScreen.cs and

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a new screen to the screen manager.
/// </summary>
public void AddScreen(GameScreen screen, PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
{
    screen.ControllingPlayer = controllingPlayer;
    screen.ScreenManager = this;
    screen.IsExiting = false;

    // If we have a graphics device, tell the screen to load content.
    if (isInitialized)
    {
        screen.LoadContent();
    }

    screens.Add(screen);

    // update the TouchPanel to respond to gestures this screen is interested in
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = screen.EnabledGestures;
}
```

as method to add a Screen to ScreenManager' list of screens.
But when I try to do something like

```
separateAxis = (ScreenManager.GameInstance as Main).SeparateAxis;
```

I get always NullReferenceException. Despite it works from other Screens (deriving directly from GameScreen, not MenuScreen).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `((Main)ScreenManager.GameInstance).SeparateAxis` work? Do you know how `as` works? Writing `(ScreenManager.GameInstance as Main).SeparateAxis` instead of `((Main)ScreenManager.GameInstance).SeparateAxis` is asking for this kind of trouble.

Comment: Relevant: [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: When do you call the problem line, is it in the consturctor of the screen, in which case the screenmanager won't be assigned a value yet.

Comment: It doesn't work neither casting with (Main), in fact this was my first try. Even if I move the line outside the constructor, in another method it always gives exception on ScreenManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 posibilies from your code, either `ScreenManager` is null, or `(ScreenManager.GameInstance as Main)` is.

---

#### For the first case:

I think you're calling your problem line from within the option screen's constructor, or at least before the screenmanager's `AddScreen` method is called.

Move it to the screen's `LoadContent` method.

#### For the second case:

Check that `GameInstance` is an instance of `Main`.

---

It's worth noting that this is the [GameStateManagement sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) you're basing your code on.

Comment: Yes, I applied that engine to my application. And yes, GameInstance is an instance of Main (in fact Main is of type Game and also GameInstance obviously is). But also trying to put that in one of the events (the LoadContent it's not there by default, I can add if it serves) it gives the same exception...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line of code. Hover your cursor over `ScreenManager`. Is it null? Hover over the `as`, is that expression null? Override the `GameScreen`'s `LoadContent` method in your `OptionsScreen`, and put the code there. That should work.